# VHDL Vending machine with an error in port map

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm doing a vending machine project, the only problem I have is the port map for Seg where I get this error:

> **Warning: COMP96_0411:** reu.vhd : (363, 31): Actual of mode 'out' cannot be assigned to formal "x" of mode 'in'.
>   **Error: COMP96_0100:** reu.vhd : (363, 36): Actual parameter type in port map does not match the type of the formal port 'display'.

in four places.

The top level of the design:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity cafe_pf is Port (
    inicio: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    ck: in std_logic;
    Unp: in std_logic;
    DoP: in std_logic;
    Ci5: in std_logic;
    DiP: in std_logic;
    Sie1: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Sie2: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Sie3: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)  ;
    Sie4: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end cafe_pf;

architecture behavioral of cafe_pf is
    type nombres_estados is (Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8,Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14,Q15,Q16,   Q17, Q18);
    signal estado: nombres_estados;
    signal entrada_aux: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

    component clk200Hz Port (
        clk_in : in STD_LOGIC;
        reset : in STD_LOGIC;
        clk_out: out STD_LOGIC
    );
    end component;

    component conta1  port(
        x: std_logic;
        clk: in std_logic;
    rst: std_logic;
    y: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component Seg7 port(
        x : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        display : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal ck2: std_logic;
    signal Unp1: std_logic;
    signal DoP2: std_logic;
    signal Ci52: std_logic;
    signal DiP2: std_logic;
    signal Sie11: std_logic;
    signal Sie21: std_logic;
    signal Sie31: std_logic;
    signal Sie41: std_logic;

begin
    cl: clk200hz port map(ck,rst,ck2);

    pulso_unpeso: conta1 port map(Unp,ck2,rst,Unp1)    ;
    pulso_dospesos: conta1 port map(DoP,ck,rst,DoP2)    ;
    pulso_cincopesos: conta1 port map(Ci5,ck,rst,Ci52)  ;
    pulso_Diezpesos: conta1 port map(Dip,ck,rst,DiP2)   ;

    entrada_aux<=DiP2&Ci52&DoP2&Unp1;

    process(inicio, ck2)
    begin
        if rst='1' and ck2'event then
            estado<=Q0;
        end if;

        if inicio='1' then
            estado<=Q0;
        elsif ck2='1' and ck2'event then
            case estado is
                when Q0 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q1 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q3;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q6;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q11;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q2 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q3;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q4;
                        when "0101" => estado<=Q7;
                        when "1010" => estado<=Q12;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q3 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q3;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q4;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "0101" => estado<=Q8;
                        when "1010" => estado<=Q13;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q4 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q4;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q6;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q9;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q14;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q5 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q6;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q7;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q10;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q15;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q6 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q6;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q7;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q8;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q11;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q16;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q7 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q7;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q8;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q9;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q12;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q17;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q8 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q8;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q9;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q10;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q13;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q18;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q9 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q10 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q11 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q12 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q13 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q14 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q15 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q16 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q17 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when Q18 =>
                    case entrada_aux is
                        when "0000" => estado<=Q0;
                        when "0001" => estado<=Q1;
                        when "0010" => estado<=Q2;
                        when "0100" => estado<=Q5;
                        when "1000" => estado<=Q10;
                        when others => estado<=Q0;
                    end case;
                when others => estado<=Q0;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(estado)
    begin
        case estado is
            when Q0 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0000";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q1 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0001";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q2 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0010";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q3 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0011";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q4 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0100";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q5 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0101";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q6 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0110";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q7 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="0111";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q8 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="1000";
                Sie3<="0000";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q9 =>
                Sie1<="0000";
                Sie2<="1001";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0000";
            when Q10 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0000";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0001";
            when Q11 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0001";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0010";
            when Q12 =>
                Sie1<="0001" ;
                Sie2<="0010";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0011";
            when Q13 =>
                Sie1<="0001" ;
                Sie2<="0011";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0100";
            when Q14 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0100";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0101";
            when Q15 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0101";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0110";
            when Q16 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0110";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="0111";
            when Q17 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="0111";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="1000";
            when Q18 =>
                Sie1<="0001";
                Sie2<="1000";
                Sie3<="0001";
                Sie4<="1001";
        end case;
    end process;

    display_1: seg7 port map(Sie1,Sie11); ------ERROR HERE
    display_2: seg7 port map(Sie2,Sie21); ------ERROR HERE
    display_3: seg7 port map(Sie3,Sie31); ------ERROR HERE
    display_4: seg7 port map(Sie4,Sie41); ------ERROR HERE

 end behavioral;
```

In each state Idisplaythe data of Sie1,2,3,4, but I get that error in the port map lines.

This is the Seg7 program:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Seg7 is port(
    x : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    display : out std_logic_vector(0 to 6)
);
end Seg7;

architecture SIMPLE1 of Seg7 is
    signal display0:std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
begin
    bcd_7seg: process(x)
    begin
        case x is
            when "0000" => display0 <= "1111110";
            when "0001" => display0 <= "0110000";
            when "0010" => display0 <= "1101101";
            when "0011" => display0 <= "1111001";
            when "0100" => display0 <= "0110011";
            when "0101" => display0 <= "1011011";
            when "0110" => display0 <= "1011111";
            when "0111" => display0 <= "1110000";
            when "1000" => display0 <= "1111110";
            when "1001" => display0 <= "1110011";
            when "1010" => display0 <= "1110111";
            when "1011" => display0 <= "0011111";
            when "1100" => display0 <= "1001110";
            when "1101" => display0 <= "0111101";
            when "1110" => display0 <= "1001111";
            when others => display0 <= "1000111";
        end case;
        display<=not display0;
    end process;
end SIMPLE1;
```

The seg7 is the program for 7 segment display, I truly don't know what in doing wrong.

UPDATE. 13/2/2015
I add the lines suggested and fix the vectors, those errors are gone,
But now i get 4 new errors.

```
Error: ELAB1_0008: reu.vhd : (370, 15): Cannot read output : "Sie1".
Error: ELAB1_0008: reu.vhd : (371, 16): Cannot read output : "Sie2".
Error: ELAB1_0008: reu.vhd : (372, 16): Cannot read output : "Sie3".
Error: ELAB1_0008: reu.vhd : (373, 16): Cannot read output : "Sie4".
```

new code:
The top level of the design(same has before, i just add this):

```
 signal Sie1_i: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
 signal Sie1_i1: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 signal Sie1_i2: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 signal Sie1_i3: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   .
   .
   .
   when Q18 =>
    Sie1<="0001";
    Sie2<="1000";
    Sie3<="0001";
    Sie4<="1001";    

   end case;    

  end process; 
  Sie1_i <= Sie1;-------- ERROR HERE
  Sie1_i1 <= Sie2; -------- ERROR HERE
  Sie1_i2 <= Sie3; -------- ERROR HERE
  Sie1_i3 <= Sie4; -------- ERROR HERE

   display_1: seg7 port map(Sie1_i, Sie11);
   display_2: seg7 port map(Sie1_i1,Sie21);
   display_3: seg7 port map(Sie1_i2,Sie31);
   display_4: seg7 port map(Sie1_i3,Sie41);

 end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display_1: seg7 port map(Sie1,Sie11); ------ERROR HERE
```

`Sie1` is an output of your entity. You can't read from an output. To get around this, normally you would do something like:

```
Sie1_i <= Sie1;
display_1: seg7 port map(Sie1_i, Sie11);
```

and have your earlier code assign to `Sie1_i`.

Comment: You could also note signal Sie11 is declared as type std_logic and the second position in the Seg7 parameter list, `display` is declared as out std_logic_vector(0 to 6).

Comment: i fix both errors thaks to you, but now i get this line of " Error: ELAB1_0008: reu.vhd : (367, 22): Cannot read output : "Sie1". i try to put another signal inside the case, but i get same error, how can i fix this, ty btw